dragenter event not fired in object embedded in Chrome
Here is a codepen which embeds another one twice:

In an <iframe>
In an <object>

In Chrome, only the iframe embed works. The object embed does not fire the dragenter event for some reason (and so the draggable element does not trigger colour change when dragged over the second block).
In Firefox, however, both work.
What's wrong with firing the event in Chrome?
UPDATE: This is a browser bug, reported here since 19 August 2024: https://issues.chromium.org/issues/360599252

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6481094/html5-drag-and-drop-ondragover-not-firing-in-chrome

@HansPassant Thanks but that's not it (I've verified that using dataTransfer.setData doesn't change anything). Here the issue is limited to when the content is loaded in an <object>. It works otherwise.
